# pywinauto (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'NoneType' and 'int')

Tags: pywinauto

I am getting the error stated in the title when selecting an item from a Combobox. I am passing the index to the select method.

Any help will be much appreciated.

python: 3.8 64 bit

pywinauto: latest version

**Error**

```
..\capture_scan\app.py:123: in new_batch
    batch(batch_class, priority, batch_name)
..\batch_manager\create_batch.py:25: in __call__
    batch_class_control.select(batch_class)
C:\Users\svc_qa_nyhixint\.virtualenvs\kofax-sIXtZgVX\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\win32_controls.py:430: in select
    self.notify_parent(win32defines.CBN_CLOSEUP)
C:\Users\svc_qa_nyhixint\.virtualenvs\kofax-sIXtZgVX\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\hwndwrapper.py:721: in notify_parent
    win32functions.MakeLong(message, controlID),

high = 8, low = None

def MakeLong(high, low):
    """Pack high into the high word of a long and low into the low word"""

    # we need to AND each value with 0xFFFF to account for numbers
    # greater then normal WORD (short) size
    return ((high & 0xFFFF) << 16) | (low & 0xFFFF)
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'NoneType' and 'int'

C:\Users\svc_qa_nyhixint\.virtualenvs\kofax-sIXtZgVX\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\win32functions.py:760: TypeError
```

**Control Identifiers**

```
['Create Batch', 'Dialog', 'Create BatchDialog']
child_window(title="Create Batch", control_type="Window")
   | 
   | Static - 'Batch class:'    (L516, T288, R658, B304)
   | ['Static', 'Batch class:', 'Batch class:Static', 'Batch class:0', 'Batch class:1', 'Static0', 'Static1', 'Batch class:Static0', 'Batch class:Static1']
   | child_window(title="Batch class:", control_type="Text")
   | 
   | ComboBox - 'Batch class:'    (L666, T286, R1232, B310)
   | ['ComboBox', 'Batch class:2', 'Batch class:ComboBox', 'ComboBox0', 'ComboBox1']
   | child_window(title="Batch class:", auto_id="27651", control_type="ComboBox")
   |    | 
   |    | Static - 'Batch class:'    (L3, T3, R542, B21)
   |    | ['Static2', 'Batch class:3', 'Batch class:Static2']
   |    | child_window(title="Batch class:", control_type="Text")
   |    | 
   |    | Button - 'Open'    (L1212, T287, R1231, B309)
   |    | ['Button', 'OpenButton', 'Open', 'Button0', 'Button1', 'OpenButton0', 'OpenButton1', 'Open0', 'Open1']
   |    | child_window(title="Open", auto_id="DropDown", control_type="Button")oreButton', 'More0', 'More1', 'MoreButton0', 'MoreButton1']
   |    | child_window(title="More", auto_id="MoreButton", control_type="Button")
   |    | 
   |    | Button - 'Less'    (L1382, T298, R1404, B310)
   |    | ['Button3', 'Less', 'LessButton', 'Less0', 'Less1', 'LessButton0', 'LessButton1']
   |    | child_window(title="Less", auto_id="LessButton", control_type="Button")
```

Comment: It looks like parent control was destroyed during some close event. Thanks for reporting it! Is it possible to access the application binaries? At least trial version? Or maybe it's possible to prepare small sample app with similar case?

Comment: The bug is tracked here: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/900

Comment: My apologies, the application is private and I do not have the expertise to create a sample app. I have attached the control identifiers it if helps.

Comment: I have added more information on GitHub to help with the issue.

Comment: This PR should fix the issue: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/pull/1084